# Go through a string and use each char but I get this exception message : " (48,1)-(50,35): Non-exhaustive patterns in function textToMorse"

Tags: haskell

```
text :: String -> String
text (x:xs)
          | length xs >= 0 = (func x morse) ++ " " ++ text xs
          | otherwise = ""
```

When I execute this it actually works as I imagined but I get additionally an exception
message : "(48,1)-(50,35): Non-exhaustive patterns in function text".
I think there is something missing, but don't know what exactly.

Comment: you are not taking care of the empty string "" case.

Comment: Code review: once you've done enough exercises like this that you feel comfortable doing manual list manipulations, you can graduate to something like `text = unwords . map (func morse)` instead. (This is in an alternate universe where `func` takes its arguments in the other order.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```hs
text :: String -> String
text [] = ""
text (x:xs) = func x morse ++ " " ++ text xs
```

When you do pattern matching, ideally, the patterns need to be exhaustive. What you are doing in your original code is to pattern match but miss the empty string case. Then you handle the empty string case in guards. This is an anti pattern. Just match on empty string in a pattern and remove the guards.

I also removed the parens around `func x morse` since `++` has lower precedence than function application, so the parens are redundant.

Comment: `x` was already a char in your posted code. since `xs` is a string, when you take it element by element, `x` becomes `char`. If `func` needs a string, you can put `x` in a list which makes it automatically a string. Like this: `[x]`. Is that what you want?

Comment: @RezanYilmaz: func is getting a variable `x` and a value named `morse`.